# React native application is stuct while running

Tags: react-native

When I run ***react-native run-android*** at that time app is stuck.

[image]

Comment: Try to stop the current gradle deamon(s) using `android/gradlew --stop` then re-run the install command with a cache clear using `react-native run-android -- --reset-cache`

Comment: It also not helped me. If I restart my mobile it runs. Unless I restart my mobile, it will not run again.

Comment: You can also try restarting your adb server by running `adb kill-server && adb start-server`

Comment: I already tried this method it is not helped me.